Failed to export sqlite data to Telegram bot (python)
I'm a beginner who barely knows coding.
2 to 8 of the 9 columns stored in the sqlite DB, and attempted to get the most recent value based on timestamp (column 1).
The code works without errors, but no message is coming.
Only the logs continue to be output.
All tokens are entered normally.

the code is written by chatgpt paid version.
Of course, when it was activated, it was executed at the right time.

What I wanted was like the instruction below.
However, only logs are output from the terminal, and no Telegram bot messages are coming.
For your reference, Let me write code too.
.instruction
##Role
You are the best Python expert in the world. Your goal is to write automation code so that dbized data can be sent as messages via Telegram bots every certain amount of time.

##Overview
I'm trying to create a Python program that sends information from file A to file in a row with Telegram messages every set time.
File A is named 'trading_decisions.sqlite' and has a DB structure.
The A file is in the same folder as the folder where I write the code.
There are a total of 9 columns in this DB, and the names are as follows.

(0) id
(1) timestamp
(2) decision
(3) percentage
(4) reason
(5) btc_balance
(6) krw_balance
(7) btc_avg_buy_price
(8) btc_krw_price

##Introducing Workflow
###### Data extraction steps:
1. ** Access the file 'trading_decisions.sqlite' within the same folder.**: This file is in DB format and configured in JSON format.

2. ** Timestamp points select the last row **: for example, if there is data on Jan. 24, 2024, Jan. 25, 2024, or Jan. 26, 2024, only select the row that corresponds to the last, Jan. 26, 2024.

3. **Here, all data except (0) are called and converted to text format**: (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7) and (8) All data are output. In this case, both the column name and the value are output, in the format "{column name}:{value} \n"\nIt's "

###Telegrambot Transfer Step:
4. **At the specified time, data is extracted according to the above criteria and messages are sent to the chat room.**: The time is based on three times a day (0:03, 8:03, 16:03) and the Telegram chat room token and my bot token are stored in the .env file.


5. Take a deep breath, and think about it step by step.


######Examples of messages being sent
.Example

“Timestamp: 2024-04-22 08:03:15

"decision": "buy",

"percentage": 20,

 "reason": "The analysis of both daily and hourly OHLCV data has revealed a noteworthy pattern: the occurrence of falling tails three times, indicating strong buying pressure and price rejection at lower levels. This pattern suggests a foundation for market reversal and potential uptrend initiation. Supported by the technical analysis, where the EMA_10 has crossed above the SMA_10, a bullish trend appears imminent. This technical signal, in conjunction with the identified pattern and positive market sentiment influenced by recent favorable crypto news, signifies increasing momentum and presents a compelling opportunity for a profitable buy decision. Aligning this decision with our risk management protocols, the consideration of the market's current state and portfolio balance suggests that allocating 20% of the portfolio to this buying opportunity optimizes the potential for profit while managing exposure to market volatility. This strategic decision leverages both technical patterns and market sentiment analysis, positioning the portfolio to capitalize on the anticipated upward market movement."

“btc_balance” : 1

“krw_balance” : 0

“btc_avg_buy_price” : 100000000

“btc_krw_price” : 100000000

.code
import os
import sqlite3
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CallbackContext, CommandHandler
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()
bot_token = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')
chat_id = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID')

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def fetch_latest_data(db_path='trading_decisions.sqlite'):
    """Fetches the latest entry from the database."""
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = """
        SELECT timestamp, decision, percentage, reason, btc_balance, krw_balance, btc_avg_buy_price, btc_krw_price
        FROM trading_decisions
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.close()

        if not data:
            logging.info("No data fetched from the database.")
            return "No new data to report."

        columns = ['timestamp', 'decision', 'percentage', 'reason', 'btc_balance', 'krw_balance', 'btc_avg_buy_price', 'btc_krw_price']
        formatted_data = "\n".join(f"{col}: {val}" for col, val in zip(columns, data))
        logging.info(f"Fetched data: {formatted_data}")
        return formatted_data
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching data: {e}")
        return "Error retrieving data."

def send_message(context: CallbackContext):
    """Sends the latest database entry as a Telegram message."""
    message = fetch_latest_data()
    if message:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Failed to fetch data.")

def test(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Manually trigger data fetch and message send."""
    send_message(context)

def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Simple echo to test bot responsiveness."""
    update.message.reply_text("Echo reply: Bot is responding!")

def main():
    """Sets up the bot application and the job queue."""
    application = Application.builder().token(bot_token).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("test", test))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("echo", echo))

    # Define timezone for GMT+9 and schedule messages
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
    times = ['00:03', '08:03', '22:08']
    for time_str in times:
        naive_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time()
        aware_datetime = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), naive_time, tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)
        local_time = aware_datetime.time()
        logging.info(f"Scheduled message at local time: {local_time}")
        application.job_queue.run_daily(send_message, time=local_time, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

